# How to move an object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello guys I try to make a city building game the idea is very simple actually Instantiate an Building and move them with mouse after that hit the place button and place.
The issue is if the collider of a another building completely encloses the collider of the building that I am built I can't move new building.
I can probably explain better with pictures.
[Issue 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNHsd.png)
The first picture my new building you can see collider limits and the second one my old building that I already placed. I Understand the problem but I can not solve it.
And here it is my object drag code

```cs
private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, 1000f,(1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"))))
        {
            Debug.Log(hitInfo.transform.name);
            transform.position = SnapToGrid(hitInfo.point);
        }
    }

    private Vector3Int SnapToGrid(Vector3 pos)
    {
        Vector3 tempPos = pos;
        Vector3Int snappedPos;
        snappedPos = new Vector3Int(Mathf.RoundToInt(tempPos.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(tempPos.y), Mathf.RoundToInt(tempPos.z));
        return snappedPos;
    }
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Hello a little update for for those who had this problem and found this thread. Some times making a "Is Trigger" not work i don't know why but i solved the problem. All I did was make the pre-placed buildings layer the Ignore raycast layer when placing the new building

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, I believe that you can solve the problem by enableing the "Is Trigger" option of the previously placed buildings colliders at the moment that a new building is being moved around. Enableing this option in an object makes it so other objects can pass trought it when collision happens.